# How to span a div 100% without using position absolute?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

This is a big problem for me, I am working on tackling scaling problems between different devices. It would be nice, if I just had a multiplier that I echoed in, unless javascript variablses can be used in place of the values for example width, height, font-size etc...

For example the banner of stackexchange is probably using position absolute to go 100% across the screen, but if you were to use div, with width 100% and floated left, there would be some space on the ends of the element.

So when I see these pages made for mobile devices, they are separated by sections using large font, and they seem to responsively scale.

How do you achieve the effect of position absolute without absolute values for width/height?

I have used PHP to echo in modified variables before the page loads.

For example

```
    <?php
    // get device screen height width via ajax post
    $width = $POST['value'];
    $height = $POST['value'];

    if(($width/$height)>1) {
    $multiplier = 10;
    }else {
    $multiplier = 1;
    }

    // process values on page

    $variable_height = $multiplier*30;
    $px = "px";
    $concat_height = $variable_height.$px;
    $new_height = $concat_height;

    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <head>
    <style>
    .full-span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: <?php echo $new_height; ?>;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="full-span">My height changes on device height</div>
</body>
```

Pretty messy sample, but I think you get the idea.

Comment: a div by it's nature is 100% width

Comment: do you get what I'm asking though? pos absolute is the actual 100% where you can't see the edges of the screen.

Comment: then remove the margin from the body tag. `body {margin: 0}`

Comment: You probably haven't removed the default margin from the `body` Also, there's probably little reason to float a div that's 100% wide.

Comment: "banner of stackexchange is probably using position absolute to go 100% across the screen". Nope. Just margin-less, with margins and borders removed from `body` and `html`.

Comment: @Aaron, okay let me try that. Thanks for all of your responses. Holy crap, it was that simple? Wow... well at any rate, thanks! That may simplify things, although I still have to come up with a solution for scaling.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of scaling, you could try...

HTML

```
<div class="full-span">
    <h1>Content</h1>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.full-span 
{
    background: url(..img/whatever.png);
    background-size: contain;
    height: 10%; /* or whatever */
    max-height: 200px; /* or whatever */
}
```